# Unable to locate the Javac Compiler using jre8

Tags: java, maven, java-8

I upgraded from `Java7` to `Java8`

```
 JAVA_HOME is C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8
```

I am trying to run maven install on a plugin and I get the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project IcrMappingReport: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\..\lib\tools.jar
```

In all the projects I updated the JRE System Library to `jre8` and also in

```
Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8
```

Can anyone tell me the problem?

Comment: One of the key differences between the JRE and the JDK is that the JDK has a compiler, the JRE doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the Java8 JDK not the JRE.

JDK stands for Java Development Kit, (includes Compiler)

JRE stands for Java Runtime Environment, so it's just for running Java Programs.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 1):

Compiler is included in `JDK`, not `JRE`.
You need a `JDK` in order to compile java source code.